# How to prevent massive file delete on Debian

Tags: debian, deleted-files

Today I noticed that I lost approximately 1 TB of very old movies in my collection. I have no idea how it happened, but [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) shows what happened. I'm pretty sure it was my fault. (I was awake at that hour, yes; but, I am not 100% sure.) How can I prevent something like that from happening again? How can I prevent myself (or a program/script) from deleting more than x GB of data? Any suggestion is welcome.
[image: Munin - Disk usage]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone who has successfully removed the `/Windows` subdirectory from a **running** windows system, AND deleted the contents of `/bin` on a **running** linux boxen (it didn't die!)... I know the feeling.  (But I don't know HOW I did the Windows thing, shouldn't be possible, Windows locks files in use.)

Several options:

- Remove write ability from containing subdirectory.  [`chmod a-w /my_movie_dir`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)
- use [`chattr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) & [`lsattr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lsattr) to set/check the **immutable** flag.  [`chattr +i`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) [`"Earth vs The Flying Saucers.m4v"`](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049169/)
- ['mount'](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) that drive/partition as **read-only** by default (see ['fstab'](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab)), requiring you to [`mount -o rw,remount /my_movie_dir`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) to do bad things.

Comment: `chattr` and the **immutable** flag as of now seems to be the best idea, I could apply it to every file that matches a certain mask. Mounting as read only isn't the best solution because every time I want to move a file to the mounted drive would be a pain. BTW, one year ago circa I made a batch script that renamed every single file in c:\windows\system32\ to *.torrent. Don't ask me how I did that. I still can't figure it out. Of course that wasn't my intent!

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the best option here might be to rename rm (or whatever you tend to use to delete stuff) and wrap that in a new rm script. By best option I don't mean best option, but its fun to think about doing this. You might just want to be more careful with your deletes.

I tested it out quickly after renaming rm to rm-real

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/rm $1
```

And that works. You can have that make use of a few functions in rm and echo yourself a little note to use rm-real for full functionality, or go through the exercise of getting the arguments right.

Edit: Actually the best option is good backups. Changing rm is fun, but as noted in the comments a bit wonky.

Comment: Watering down the commands *will* bite you when you sit in front of a non-neutered Linux system. Learn not to do foolish commands. This is the first lesson on that class.

Comment: This doesn't help deletions through a GUI though, nor `find . -iname "Earth*" -delete`, or Midnight Commander, or , or , ...

Comment: The best solution in my opinion would be a script that changes `rm`. This script should check if the amount of data that you are trying to delete is greater than x MB. If it is greater than X it should ask you "are you really sure you want to delete this amount of data?" Do you think that this would be possible?

Comment: I mean, what road should I follow? I just need a path to follow, or a start point.

Comment: I think the chattr idea above is much better then what's going on here. Backups still good though.

Comment: Yes I just bought another hard disk to backup everything. But what if everything is deleted from hdd1 and since it is synced to hdd2 (backup) everithing is deleted on hdd2 too?

Comment: This is really another question, but the short answer is you need to make sure your backup strategy accounts for that. Either by never deleting synced data, but moving it to another folder, or by having a rotating backup. Most backup packages will account for this.

Comment: Thank you, I will search for an already answered question or post a new one about this topic.